# Is is possible to disable certain javascript script in selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Is is possible to somehow dissable javascript script in google chrome selenium ? The scripts launches once I log in and collects the data about actions performed. It also appears to be in network tab (developer console) as GET request.

Answer (score 0):

This code will disable all javascript in selenium chrome:

```
@Test() public void Chrome_javascript_disable() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\AnkitP\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map < String, Object > prefs = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
    prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript", 2);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/imghp");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("flowers");
    driver.findElement(By.className("Tg7LZd")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
```